# Knife tool not appearing in toolbar

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender.

I'm trying to cut a cylinder in half vertically but I don't see the knife tool in the toolbar.

I see what follows:

[image]

Comment: Switch to Edit Mode.

Comment: I'm already in edit mode

Comment: https://docs.blender.org for the manual. It’s got decent chapters :-) TYJ.

Comment: I ask because I've already searched for it and I have time contrain. Could you please help me?

Comment: I guess you have a surface object because its name. Knife tool only for mesh objects.

Comment: Solved, thank you!

Comment: @DavideModesto Hello and welcome. Please don't turn your questions into guessing games, provide factual info we can use to diagnose the issue. A severely cropped screenshot that doesn't show the UI or the object is not much to go by. We aim to be a a high quality database of answers that are above all expected to help future visitors, rather than provide assistance on time constraints.